# How do I to label a column header as a formatted date?

Tags: mysql, pivot, date-format

### What I have:

I have the following query that gets me pretty much what I need:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT(
       'MAX(IF(Date = ''',
        Date,
        ''', Description, NULL)) AS ',
       CONCAT("'",Date,"'")
     )
   ) INTO @sql
FROM updates;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Action, ', @sql, ' FROM updates GROUP BY Action');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

And gives the following output:

[image]

### What I need:

What I would like is for the Column headers to be in the following format examples:

> day/month/year
>
> 04/10/2016
>
> %d/%m/&Y

### What I have tried:

I have tried a number of different alterations to my code (far too many minor changes to list here) but each time I seem to get an error, to which I am guessing is regarding the formatting/syntax of the query.

Below is one example I tried to show the wave of thinking I was on:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT(
       'MAX(IF(Date = ''',
       Date,
       ''', Description, NULL)) AS ',
       CONCAT("'",Date_Format(Date, "'"%d/%m/%Y"'"),"'")
     )
   ) INTO @sql
FROM updates;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Action, ', @sql, ' FROM updates GROUP BY Action');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

As you can see I tried to set the "AS" value (Column name) using the DATE_FORMAT snippet of code. However, when I run this, I get the following error after the "FROM updates;" and before the "INTO @sql":

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '%m/%Y"'"),"'")

This in turn gives me the following error message after the PREPARE stmt FROM @sql:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

If anyone has any idea how to help me with this or point me in the right direction, I will be very grateful!

Comment: What is the format that you want?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add this to the question. Day-Month-Year so %d/%m/%Y (Example: 04/10/2016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `select concat(date_format(now(), '%d/%m/%Y'))` gives me `11/10/2016`.

This is working perfectly fine. I guess you should consider removing the double-quotes. That should do the trick.

Comment: Removing the double quotes around the output format style ('%d/%m/%Y') did the trick but I was almost certain I had already tried this! I guess in all the different tests I did, I just missed this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! I had been through this. :)